# Can a user-defined class have custom behavior with std::cout <<?

Tags: c++, class, cout

Suppose I have a class `Crate`, and it has two members, `width` and `height`. Now suppose I want the line `std::cout << myCrate << '\n';` to print this:

```
#---#
|   |
|   |
#---#
```

if `myCrate` has  `width = 5` and `height = 4`. Different `width`s and `height`s should result in different crate sizes. Can I define this behavior, e.g. through overloading the `<<` operator? How would I go about doing this?

Keep in mind that this is a generic example and not specific to the `Crate` class above.

Comment: Through overloading the `<<` operator.

Comment: I'd like more specific instructions.

Comment: You will find more specific instructions in the book you are learning C++ from. stackoverflow.com is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Use your favorite search engine to look for e.g. `c++ overload operator <<`. Or [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read.

Comment: Try to scrape up something yourself first, consult SO only if something goes wrong.

Comment: "Look it up". Thanks for the great advice guys, hadn't thought of that \s

Comment: We will gladly help you if you only show some effort. If all you want is a ready-made solution then this isn't the right place.

Comment: If you read the question you'll find that this is a generic example, and I'm looking for a quick instructive piece of example code. I'm not asking you to do my work for me, I'm asking you to help me understand a concept with an example. Excuse me so much if that was too much to ask of you your royal excellencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by overloading `operator<<` as shown below. By declaring the function as a `friend` of Crate, it will have access to all private data members, allowing you to represent the data however you see fit.

Crate.hpp

```
class Crate {
   ...
   friend std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& os, const Crate& c );
   ...
}
```

Crate.cpp

```
std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& os, const Crate& c ) {
   os << "whatever you want to print"

   return os;
}
```